# AngularJS inject issue

Tags: angularjs

recently I'm learning AngularJS and for below snippet code, i have no idea why doing that. Could you help me to understand it, thanks.

```
 // ----------------- this part --------------
 // mainModule.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
 // mainModule.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
 // mainModule.filter = $filterProvider.register;
 // mainModule.factory = provide.factory;
 // mainModule.service = provide.service;
```

And the following is the whole code for your reference.

```
var mainModule = angular.module('app.test', [])
.run(['$log', function ($log) {
    $log.debug('app.test.run()...');
}])
.config(function ($controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, scriptDependencyProvider, $stateProvider) {
    'use strict'; 

     mainModule.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
     mainModule.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
     mainModule.filter = $filterProvider.register;
     mainModule.factory = provide.factory;
     mainModule.service = provide.service;

    $stateProvider.state({
        name: 'main',
        url: '/main',
        views: {
            '@': {
                controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'appTranslation',
                    function ($scope, $stateParams, appTranslation) {
                        appTranslation.load([appTranslation.main]);
                    }],
                template: '<main-view></main-view>',
            }
        },
        resolve: scriptDependencyProvider.createDependenciesMap(scriptDependencyProvider.main),
       deepStateRedirect: true,
        sticky: true
    });
});
```

Comment: where did you get this code from? I don't see why you would need any of what is shown in the comment block

Comment: Please try to explain more of what issue you're experiencing. Is there an error getting thrown in console? If so, what?

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks. my question is that what's the meaning of the following code, those code was getting from current project

Comment: @charlietfl, what's the meaning, 
ainModule.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
     mainModule.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
     mainModule.filter = $filterProvider.register;
     mainModule.factory = provide.factory;
     mainModule.service = provide.service;

Comment: @forrestmid, actually there is no any issue, i just went through those code and no idea what's the meaning there, so i post it here and want to understand the meaning ainModule.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
     mainModule.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
     mainModule.filter = $filterProvider.register;
     mainModule.factory = provide.factory;
     mainModule.service = provide.service;

Comment: @Jacob It all looks like it is defining properties that already exist in a module and is completely redundant  That's why i asked where you got that from

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for your prompt reply. actually i just got the code from internal project which written by another people. And I was confused with this code, hope you could help me to clarify. thanks.

Comment: Sorry...makes no sense to me why they put any of that in the project. I don't think anything would break if you removed it